# tMysqlBulkExec Error (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: sql-server, talend, bulkinsert

I want to insert a csv file into a database using tMysqlOutputBulk and tMysqlBulkExec or (tMysqlOutputBulkExec). The file and database are on a distant server.

So far my job look like this :[image]

And I always get this error even after checking the path (Sorry it's in french) :

Chargement en masse impossible car le fichier "/disk1/apps/SIN/test/mssql_data.txt" est impossible à ouvrir. Code d'erreur du système d'exploitation 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

The file is created in the specified directory of tMysqlOutputBulk component and I even changed the rights but I still get this error.

Comment: Can you give us both the filenames used by the 2 components ?

Comment: The csv file being loaded is FBT01.dat and the file created by tMysqlOutputBulk is mssql_data.txt

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear : can you show the whole path for the 2 tMSSqlBulk components ?